# How to use XSLT to convert a XML to Table [CODE UPDATED 11/6]

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file want to convert to a Table OR CSV by XSLT. I tried by Altova MapForce 2014to map the columns but still,not able to gen out the outcomes. thanks a lot.

XML file I have

```
<Records>
    <Person id="756252" date="15-Oct-2014">
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <NameDetails>
            <Name NameType="Primary Name">
                <NameValue>
                    <FirstName>Ken</FirstName>
                    <Surname>Wu</Surname>
                </NameValue>
            </Name>
            <Name NameType="AKA">
                <NameValue>
                    <FirstName>Kenneth</FirstName>
                    <Surname>Wu</Surname>
                </NameValue>
            </Name>
            <Name NameType="AKA2">
                <NameValue>
                    <FirstName>CAN</FirstName>
                    <Surname>Wu</Surname>
                </NameValue>
            </Name>
        </NameDetails>
        <Descriptions>
            <Description Description1="11" Description2="12" Description3="13"/>
            <Description Description1="21" Description2="22" Description3="23"/>
            <Description Description1="31" Description2="32" Description3="33"/>
        </Descriptions>
        <DateDetails>
        <Date DateType="Date of Birth">
            <DateValue Year="1990" />
            <DateValue Year="1991" />
        </Date>
        <Date DateType="Date of Issue">
            <DateValue Year="2000" />
            <DateValue Year="2001" />
        </Date>
        </DateDetails>
    </Person>
    <Person id="253555" date="14-Oct-2014">
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <NameDetails>
            <Name NameType="Primary Name">
                <NameValue>
                    <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
                    <Surname>Lai</Surname>
                </NameValue>
            </Name>
        </NameDetails>
        <Descriptions>
            <Description Description1="11" Description2="12" Description3="13"/>
            <Description Description1="21" Description2="22"/>
        </Descriptions>
        <Date DateType="Date of Birth">
            <DateValue Year="1992" />
        </Date>
    </Person>
</Records>
```

expected outcome

```
|ID     |Date        |Gender |NameType     |FirstName |SurName |Description1 |Description2 |Description3 |DateType      |Year|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Birth |1990|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |1991|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |2000|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Ken       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA          |Kenneth   |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |21           |22           |23           |Date of Issue |2001|
|756252 |15-Oct-2014 |Male   |AKA2         |CAN       |Wu      |31           |32           |33           |Date of Issue |2001|
|253555 |14-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Peter     |Lai     |11           |12           |13           |Date of Issue |1992|
|253555 |14-Oct-2014 |Male   |Primary Name |Peter     |Lai     |21           |22           |             |Date of Issue |1992|
```

XSL i create for testing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Records</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>NameType</th>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>SurName</th>
      <th>Description1</th>
      <th>Description2</th>
      <th>Description3</th>
     </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="Records/Person/NameDetails/Name">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@date"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Gender"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@NameType"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="NameValue/FirstName"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="NameValue/Surname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Descriptions/Description/@Description1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Descriptions/Description/@Description2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Descriptions/Description/@Description3"/></td>
     </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you tried?

Comment: no:( because i were using Altova MapForce 2014 to do it, not sure how to export the XSLT, i am sorry for that

Comment: Did you write this stylesheet yourself or is this the result you are getting from MapForce? Or something else completely?

Comment: yes i did  write this style sheet myself , now the one i updated in main post, it okay to get the data,BUT expected outcome still not meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two nested loops here:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="Records/Person/NameDetails/Name">
    <xsl:variable name="NameType" select="@NameType"/>
    <xsl:variable name="FirstName" select="NameValue/FirstName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Surname" select="NameValue/Surname"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../../Descriptions/Description">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Gender"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$NameType"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$FirstName"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$Surname"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description1"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description2"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description3"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

---

### Edit:

To avoid storing all name details in individual variables, you can do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records/Person/NameDetails/Name">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../Descriptions/Description">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@date"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Gender"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$name/@NameType"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$name/NameValue/FirstName"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$name/NameValue/Surname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description1"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description2"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description3"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

### Edit 2:

Here's an example of 3 nested loops, adding the dates you have added in your latest edit.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records/Person/NameDetails/Name">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../DateDetails/Date/DateValue">
        <xsl:variable name="dateval" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../../../Descriptions/Description">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Gender"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$name/@NameType"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$name/NameValue/FirstName"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$name/NameValue/Surname"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description1"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description2"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description3"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$dateval/../@DateType"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$dateval/@Year"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: oh, yes, it works, but may i ask, if we can have a more flexible way to do the same, because, the file could have 74 child and each of them may have 3 layer down. i am not sure i can write nested loops to all of it :(   thanks.

Comment: @user3724711 "*the file could have 74 child and each of them may have 3 layer down.*" Not sure what you mean by "child" and "layer" here.

Comment: hi, sorry i did not make clear,  i updated the XML file and expected outcome in Main post, what i mean is I have a lot of columes need to be add in, like this time i add  Date and Year. In this case, child is the <Date>  layer is <DateValue Year="2000" /> ...

Comment: @michael.hor257k Your second approach is rather offputting. You're going around your elbow to get to your thumb. Why not just store the current Name node in a variable and then access it using `$name/@NameType`.

Comment: @user3724711 "*i am not sure i can write nested loops to all of it*" I don't see that you have much choice - unless you can point to some kind of a **rule** could be used to automate the nesting. I don't see such rule myself, and I suspect that even if found, the complexity of coding would not be reduced.

Comment: right, let me think about it, actually I can try to use C# load the xml, and find out the depth, see if i can automate the nesting and out put a xlst file. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can accomplish this using templates. To increase the number of levels of permutations, you'll just need to increase the number of templates, and pass more and more parameters from one to the next:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Records</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>NameType</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>SurName</th>
            <th>Description1</th>
            <th>Description2</th>
            <th>Description3</th>
            <th>DateType</th>
            <th>Year</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Person" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Date/DateValue" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DateValue">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Person/NameDetails/Name">
      <xsl:with-param name="date" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:param name="date" select="/.." />

    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Person/Descriptions/Description">
      <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$date" />
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Description">
    <xsl:param name="date" select="/.." />
    <xsl:param name="name" select="/.." />

    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../@date"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../Gender"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name/@NameType"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name/NameValue/FirstName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name/NameValue/Surname"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description1"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description2"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description3"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$date/../@DateType"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$date/@Year"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see what advantage using templates brings to the game.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The main advantage is that they prevent it from becoming a deeply-nested clump of code, which is good given how many levels of permutations OP wants to do. Many people would also suggest that using templates is more idiomatic in XSLT, and I prefer them over `for-each` when it's practical to do so (and it almost always is).

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree this time. Your method is just as deeply-nested clump of code, with the further disadvantage of having to send an ever-increasing number of parameters down the line - à la a Simon game. I am not sure what your definition of "messy" is, but I certainly see more opportunity for error here than in the alternative.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I think you and I differ in our definition of "deeply-nested clump", as each of my templates is clear, concise, and shallowly nested. The accumulation of passed parameters is an unfortunate consequence, but the templates allow a more loosely-coupled approach that can be altered without disentangling a clump of nested elements.

Comment: "*I think you and I differ in our definition of "deeply-nested clump"*" Indeed we do. And what you see as "*a more loosely-coupled approach*", is "*a maze of interlinked templates*" to me. This is not a case where each template is an individual encapsulated process; this is a cascading flow - and I prefer to see it all in one place, not having to hunt it down.